# can I create a dataframe in r based on a range of variables

Tags: r, dataframe, range

I am trying to transition over to data analysis using r.

using an array of 4 variables: `X1 X2 X3 X4`, I want to create a dataframe

```
newVar <- data.frame (datafile$X1, datafile$X2, datafile$X3, datafile$X4)
```

This works fine with a few variables. However, I have some dataframes which include 50 or more variables.

How do I specify a range (i.e., `datafile$X1` thru `datafile$X4`)?

Comment: It sounds like in your data the files can be of different lengths. This will create some challenges for you. 

I'd recommend taking a look a read through the following page, or looking up information on joining techniques

https://stat545.com/join-cheatsheet.html

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
newVar <- data.frame (datafile[,paste0('X', 1:4)])
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. 
Can you explain the meaning of the components in (datafile[,paste0('X', 1:4)]?
Specifically, what does the "paste0 and 'X" signify?

Comment: paste0("X",1:4) means that "X" will be pasted with 1,2,3 and 4 respectively, thus giving X1, X2, X3 and X4, just like @ThomasIsCoding explained

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing previous response to be based dynamically based on number of columns:

```
newVar <- data.frame (datafile[,paste0('X', 1:ncol(datafile)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `datafile` is already a data frame, then you can use

```
newVar <- datafile[paste0("X",1:4)]
```

Comment: thanks very much, in order to understand why this works, can you please explain the paste0("X"  components?

Comment: @TGEE `paste0("X",1:4)` means that "X" will be pasted with `1`,`2`,`3` and `4` respectively, thus giving `X1`, `X2`, `X3` and `X4`